# FO.NET XSL-FO Capabilities

Tags: c#, xml, pdf, xslt, xsl-fo

I'm going to try to ask a very broad question here, not related to any specific code, but rather to an expected outcome. This is to see if anyone can answer with some certainity that FO.NET will be able to produce this outcome for me.

**My goal:** to port a service generating a PDF based on an XML document from Java (Using Apache FOP) to C#. This is to make it easier in a setup with only using IIS as a host.

**Where I'm at:** I have a working wcf service that gets the XML document and transforms it to xsl-fo and returns to the browser a PDF. What's left to do is to fix the styling so that it matches the previous PDF generated by Java Apache FOP. I'm currently using FO.NET and I'm hoping I don't have to redo everything but if that's the case then so be it.

The XSL Stylesheet is using SVG for creating figures, importing images etc and I know that this is not supported in FO.NET but maybe there is a workaround. The images can be converted to another file format but the shapes might be trickier.

Expected outcome (as it is with the current service): https://i.stack.imgur.com/zxEJA.jpg

Current outcome: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nVrm4.jpg

**Question:** Can this be done using FO.NET? If not, Is there any other Open Source Lib that I can use that is better suited or do I have to solve this in another way?

The reason I'm trying to use XSL-FO is that we already have three stylesheets defining the output PDF (There will be three different PDF Outputs) and it would be nice not having to redo everything using for instance CSS.

Comment: What is most important, a setup with IIS as the only host or a situation where you don't have to rely on workarounds (that might not even exist) for an obsolete library? Apache FOP had its latest release just a few weeks ago (June 3). FO.NET is based on a very old version of Apache FOP and has not been maintained for years.

Comment: The reason for having IIS as the only host is to enable all (three) services to use the same port as the customers using this product often only have one open port available. If this is easier to setup I would go for that and maybe in the future, to continue the development using CSS.

Comment: I know that you want an open source solution, but I just wanted to mention the commercial FO processor Antenna House which very likely would solve most of your XSL-FO issues. It is not cheap, but it comes with a .NET interface: http://www.antennahouse.com/product/ahf60/docs/ahf-dotnet.html.

Comment: Why not develop an interface .NET to Java. It can certainly be done in several ways. RenderX's XEPWin product is done that way exposing a .NET API to the underlying Java software. Or use web services internally in your application, using your .NET application to call a FOP-based web service internally on the same machine.

Comment: Thank you @KevinBrown, yeah I set that up yesterday using ARR for IIS to serve as a Proxy for the Tomcat server.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to answer this myself, partly based on the response I recieved, partly on my own experience with using FO.NET. I Don't recommend using C# for PDF's if xsl-fo is used for styling. If C# is a requirement I would investigate CSS for this purpose instead. If C# is not a requirement, I would recommend using Java and Apache FOP and host it here. If you, as in my case, need to host multiple services on the same outgoing port, you can use Application Request Routing in IIS (Addon I think) to serve as a reverse proxy for your Java Servlet. Thanks for your feedback @mzjn!